# How to use the autorotate plugin in ImageResizer

Tags: c#, autorotate, imageresizer

How do I use the AutoRotate plugin in a c# console application? I thought I'd be able to do something like `settings.AutoRotate = true;` like I can change the fit mode to use the seam carving plugin.

I've tried `settings.Add("autorotate","true")` to the keycollection, as well as other keynames `AutoRotate` and `autoRotate`.

I'm using it in a simple method.

```
    new AutoRotate().Install(ImageResizer.Configuration.Config.Current);
    ...
    protected static Image ResizeImage(Image image, double scaleFactor)
    {
        var settings = new ResizeSettings
        {
            Scale = ScaleMode.Both,
            Width = (int)Math.Floor(Image.Width * scaleFactor),
            Height = (int)Math.Floor(Image.Height * scaleFactor),
            Mode = FitMode.None,
            Format = "png"
        };

        settings.Set("autorotate", "true");
        return ImageBuilder.Current.Build(image, settings, true);
    }
```

Comment: Did you install it with `new AutoRotate().Install(Config.Current);`?

Comment: Where do I install it? Simply in the code before using it?

Comment: Yes. Just only install it once - you'll cause errors if you try to install it multiple times to the same config instance. (Config.Current is app-wide)

Comment: Yes, I've just tried installing it, and then added the key "autorotate" with the value "true" with `settings.Add("autorotate","true")` and it hasn't auto rotated the image.

Comment: This begs the question, is the seam carving plugin auto installed? I've been using it and no exceptions have been thrown.

Comment: I think we'll need to see all your code - make a [gist](http://gist.github.com) if it's more than a few lines.

Comment: The suggestion from @ComputerLinguist solved the same problem for me, and it worked with lowercased strings in `settings.Add("autorotate","true")`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a lot of research, I've found the error that I'm making, and reveals a nice little "hidden feature" of .Net!

When an image is read into the Bitmap object, the meta data is erased, so, by accepting an Image object, the data about the orientation is lost and auto rotate doesn't kick in. So, passing the image filename instead of the image object, and my code above above works!

Thanks guys!

Comment: **Always let ImageResizer deal in filenames or Streams. If you pass an Image/Bitmap (in -or- out), you bypass important image encoding/decoding work, and may introduce a memory leak.**