# How to auto-rotate an uploaded image

Tags: c#, autorotate, imageresizer

I have a site where I'm allowing the users to upload photos. These files are uploaded to my WebAPI endpoint as `HttpPostedFile`. After performing some validation on the uploaded file, I get the stream:

```
var stream = httpPostedFile.InputStream;
```

And then resize:

```
        var instructions= new Instructions
        {
            Width = 80, Height = 80,
            OutputFormat = OutputFormat.Jpeg,
            Mode = FitMode.Crop,
            AutoRotate = true
        };

        var smallResizedImage = new MemoryStream();
        var imageJob = new ImageJob(stream, smallResizedImage, instructions);
        imageJob.Build();
```

Notice how in the instructions, I specify that the image should be rotated. However my image does not get rotated, but is resized correctly.

I've even tried setting the key, but I get the same results:

```
instructions.Add("autorotate", "true");
```

I am using ImageResizer version 3.4.3 without any extra plugins or changes to configuration settings.

Based on a [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18710408/84395) by Nathanael Jones, I am not copying my stream into a Bitmap or Image, so I don't think that the EXIF information is being removed.

Comment: What is "AutoRotate = true" supposed to do exactly? What's the expected result? Clockwise?

Comment: Based on the EXIF information in the photo, it will know what angle the photo was taken, so it can auto rotate it.

Comment: Did you verify that the AutoRotate plugin is installed?

Comment: That's one thing that I'm confused about. In v4, it is built in, however, I'm using 3.4.3 which I got from Nuget where under "Functionality in this package" has "2. Pre-rotate or flip (based on gravity sensor OR manual angle).", so I'm assuming it is installed. Yet the v3 documentation on AutoRotate plugin says it's part of the Essential Edition, which I don't know how to get.

Comment: Just [follow the installation steps for AutoRotate in v3](http://imageresizing.net/docs/v3/plugins/autorotate). It's included in ImageResizer.dll, but not registered by default.

Comment: Yeah, that was it! I just didn't have it registered. Thank you!